# How to get data of multiple sheets from an excel sheet in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

```
${file} Normalised Path _downloads
{Filename} get file name important file xlsx true

Open Excel Document ${file}/${filename} importantfile

${Sheet1} Get Sheet review

${Exceldata} create list

For ${row} IN @{sheetvalues}
    Continue for loop if ${row}[0]=='date'

Append to list ${exceldata} ${row}

END
```

This is giving value for only one sheet. How can I get datas of multiple sheets

Comment: Can anyone answer this at earliest please

Comment: How about if you start by formatting your code and telling us what have you tried and with what results?

Comment: I have pasted the code after formatting only. I tried this code but it's giving me only sheet value sheet name review

Comment: This is how I have written code in Robot framework ride

Comment: You can start by reading the documentation for [ExcelLibrary](http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/ExcelLibrary-KeywordDocumentation.html#Read%20Cell%20Data%20By%20Coordinates). Also, when I search for your problem, several similar questions pop up here on stackoverflow. Read them as well.

Comment: I am using get sheet names to get all sheet names but it's throwing me error of no keyword found.

Comment: Whereas in excel library the keyword is there.. I have checked all the questions similar to this but none of them helped

Comment: `throwing me error of no keyword found` that's obviously a problem to solve before everything else. I don't see this in your original question, yet it's a blocker for you. Again, this "no keyword found" is a common problem in RF, you can now search for that.

Comment: Just now I tried with this for getting sheet names I used the exact key Get Sheet Names. Can you please help me in this. Or share a code which can get values from every sheet

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy.

1/ First step is to install the library:

```
$ pip install robotframework-excellib
```

https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-excellib/

There's also another ExcelLibrary, but this [one](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-excel10library/) is not supported in Python 3.x.

2/ Create an example test case:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ExcelLibrary     

*** Test Cases *** 
Read Excel
    Open Excel Document    test.xlsx    doc_id=test
    ${value}=    Read Excel Cell    1    1    List2
    Log To Console    ${value}
```

The point here is to open the Excel document first, and then read a cell value from a specific sheet. What sheet you want is specified as the third argument in `Read Excel Cell`.

Everything is well-documented: https://rawgit.com/peterservice-rnd/robotframework-excellib/master/docs/ExcelLibrary.html

Comment: I know, that's where your invention comes in. You need to adapt my example to your specific needs.

Comment: How can I create list 2 ? Which you have specified for sheet name

Comment: This won't work. I'm not gonna work instead of you. I linked all the resources you might need to solve this problem. You don't seem to have read any since your answers keep coming in 1 minute intervals. If you don't want to spend some time learning it yourself, I can't be of more help here.

Comment: I just wrote the code ${sheets} Get List Sheet Names and it's giving me all the sheet names. Can you please help me how can I get all the data from all sheets. Because I don't want from a specified cell. I want all values

Comment: I am trying my level best and doing whatever reply is coming.. so now I got all sheet names. Please help me to proceed

Comment: I need help on this. Can anyone please help me on this. I am getting sheet names how can I get all datas

Comment: @liki Stackoverlflow is not a forum, but a place where we help you figure out your technical difficulties. Not help you fulfill your commitments.

Comment: That's why I asked here thinking I will get some idea. But dint get any help as I tried every possibility things. And please if you dint help that's fine.